# Best way to handle uninitialised class values in TypeScript - Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, tsc

I've created a wrapper class for S3 operations but when I compile using the TypeScript complier I get the following error:

```
lib/Store.ts:20:15 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

20         await this.store.upload({
```

I'm new to TypeScript but I understand TypeScript is doing it's job here and preventing the possibility that `await this.store.upload()` could run while `this.store` is `null`. What's the correct way for dealing with this type of situation where a class value might not yet be initialised?

My wrapper class:

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

export class Store {
    storeName: string;
    store: S3 | null;
    initialised: boolean;
   
    constructor(storeName: string) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.store = null;
        this.initialised = false;
    }
    
    _init(): void {
        this.store = new S3();
    }

    async _writeToStore(data: object, path: string): Promise<void>  {
        if (!this.initialised) this._init();
        await this.store.upload({
            Bucket: this.storeName,
            Key: path,
            Body: data
        }).promise();
    }
}
```

I've always tried to avoid creating new instances of classes in the constructor because it's awkward to mock.
Maybe passing a new class instance into the constructor is the best approach?

Comment: If you know that your logic prevents `this.store` from ever being `null`, then use a non-null assertion (`this.store!`) or optional chaining operators (`this.store?.upload(...)?.promise()`).

Comment: @iz_, if you use optional chaining, you need to provide an alternative Promise to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is giving you that error because you have `strictNullChecks` enabled and your property `store` has `null` as a possible type.

You can do any of these options

##### Option 1 - Remove `null` type

You can probably drop the `null` type on `store`, since you are setting the value of that property on your constructor, and nothing on your code sets it to `null`:

```
  store: S3;
```

##### Option 2 - Add non-null assertion operator

Alternatively, if `this.store` is never going to be null when you execute `this.store.upload({...})`, then you can add a [non-null assertion operator (!)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) like this:

```
  this.store!.upload({...})
```

That will tell Typescript to stop giving the error. Note that this doesn’t change the runtime behavior of your code, so it's important to only use `!` when you know that the value can't be `null` or `undefined`.

##### Option 3 - Check `store` for `null` value right before

You can explicitly check `this.store` for null value right before calling `this.store.upload()`. But this call must be done within the same method, like this:

```
   if (!this.store) {
      this.store = new S3();
   }
   await this.store.upload({...});
```

This won't work:

```
   if (!this.store) {
      this._init();
   }
   await this.store.upload({...});
```

#### Conclusion

Personally, I would go with option 1. I'm assuming that your reason for writing a wrapper for `S3` is so that your consumers never have to instantiate and work directly with an `S3` object and instead instantiate and work with your wrapper class/object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
{
...
"strictNullChecks": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": true,
...
}

"**strictNullChecks**" tells the compiler to watch for any declared variables that evaluate to null or undefined and raise on error on at compiler time (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)
"**strictPropertyInitialization**" tells the compiler to raise an error '***when a class property was declared but not set in the constructor***'.
(https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization)